# subseting in a for loop

Tags: r, rbind

My dataset has 34,000 rows and 353 columns. One column is location and it has 11,000 unique values.  I want to subset the dataset within a for loop. I can do this by creating a new data frame for each subset, but I want the subsets to form a single data frame. I have included a sample dataset below

```
structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Car", "DOG", "House"), class = "factor"), Y = c(20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 410L, 410L, 410L, 410L, 60L), Z = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("ARGENTINA", "BERLIN GERMANY", 
"BUENOS AIRES ARGENTINA", "DUBLIN IRELAND", "FROM AUSTRIA", "GERMANY", 
"IN TRANSIT FROM GERMANY", "RIVER PLATE ARGENTINA"), class = "factor"), 
K = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")),
.Names = c("X", "Y", "Z", "K"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I can use the following code to create new data frames

```
 l=c("ARGENTINA","IRELAND")
for(i in l){
     assign(paste("newdata",i,sep=""),
     subset(TESTL[which(grepl(i,TESTL$Z)&
     !grepl("IN TRANSIT",TESTL$Z)&!grepl("FROM",TESTL$Z)),],
      select=c("X","Y","Z")))}
```

However I want to create a single new dataframe to hold all the subsets. I have tried the following code

```
d<-data.frame()
for(i in l){d<-rbind(d,c(
subset(TESTL[which(grepl(i,TESTL$Z) & !grepl("IN TRANSIT",TESTL$Z)
& !grepl("FROM",TESTL$Z)),],
    select=c("X","Y","Z")))}
```

I get the following errors

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "DOG") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "DUBLIN IRELAND") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I have attempted to convert the factors to characters with no success. Any help appreciated

Comment: Two comments: 1) Warning messages are not errors. 2) You're using `subset` in a really weird way.

Comment: The problem is that the data frame that gets created in the first iteration of your loop doesn't have all the levels of factors that try to get added later. The levels are locked at the creation of the dataframe, so additionally levels introduced later are coerced to `NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making your life rather difficult by using `assign` here and trying to store the subsets in separate data frames. Try something more like this:

```
l <- c("ARGENTINA","IRELAND")
res <- setNames(vector("list",length(l)),l)

for (i in seq_along(l)){                 
    res[[i]] <- dat[grepl(l[i],dat$Z) & !grepl("IN TRANSIT",dat$Z) & !grepl("FROM",dat$Z),c("X","Y","Z")]
}

> res
$ARGENTINA
    X  Y                      Z
1 Car 20              ARGENTINA
2 Car 20 BUENOS AIRES ARGENTINA
3 Car 20  RIVER PLATE ARGENTINA
4 Car 20              ARGENTINA

$IRELAND
    X   Y              Z
8 DOG 410 DUBLIN IRELAND


> do.call("rbind",res)
              X   Y                      Z
ARGENTINA.1 Car  20              ARGENTINA
ARGENTINA.2 Car  20 BUENOS AIRES ARGENTINA
ARGENTINA.3 Car  20  RIVER PLATE ARGENTINA
ARGENTINA.4 Car  20              ARGENTINA
IRELAND     DOG 410         DUBLIN IRELAND
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings is becouse at first iteration of a loop (ARGENTINA) it introduces factors variables X and Z, and on the second indtroduce IRELAND with another factor levels. So:

First you should change a classes of your vaiables n `TESTL`:

```
for (i in names(TESTL) [grep ("factor", sapply (TESTL, class))]) {
  TESTL[[i]] <- as.character (TESTL[[i]])
 }
```

Then it will work with the next code:

```
d <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)
for(i in l){d <- rbind(d,
        TESTL [grepl(i,TESTL$Z) & !grepl("FROM|IN TRANSIT", TESTL$Z), c("X", "Y", "Z")])}
```